# Java use generics to set the primitive type of an array later

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to write some simple numerical code in Java where one can choose between a float and double later. A simplified version of my class looks like the example below:

```
public class UniformGrid<T> {

    public T[] data;

    public UniformGrid(int arrayDim) {

        data = new T[arrayDim];

    }
}
```

This didn't work I got a `generic array creation` error when trying to compile. Googling and reading some SO answers I learned about `java.lang.reflect.Array` and tried to use

```
    data = (T[]) Array.newInstance(T.class, arrayDim);
```

Which also didn't work, since T is (probably) a primitive type. My Java knowledge is quite rusty (especially when it comes to generics) and I would like to know why the new operator cannot be used with a generic array type. Also of course I am interested in how one would solve this problem in Java.

Comment: On the right hand side when you are instantiating an array you should specify the type always..You can't use T at that time

Comment: Did you expect to be able to do `UniformGrid<float>` and `UniformGrid<double>`? One of the issues with Java is that not everything is an object. Primitives, like `float` and `double` are not first-class citizens and can't be used in generics.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation (There are some good answers there too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create a generic array in Java because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The easiest way to get around this would be to use a a `List<T>`. But if you must use an array, you can use an `Object[]` for your array and ensure that only `T` objects are put into it. (This is the strategy `ArrayList` takes.)

Ex:

```
private Object[] data = new Object[10];
private int size = 0;

public void add(T obj) {
    data[size++] = obj;
}

public T get(int i){
    return (T) data[i];
}
```

Of course you'll get an unchecked warning from your compiler, but you can suppress that.

Comment: Soo.. I simply can't use generics for primitive types?!

Comment: @Nils You cannot use a primitive type with generics (Try `new ArrayList<int>();`, it doesn't work). You can, however, use the wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, `Short`, `Byte`, `Boolean`, `Long`) and let autoboxing do its magic.

Comment: @Nils: yes. Jeffrey: And how would you perform computations on those instances of T? And how would you store the result?

Comment: @meriton If you knew ahead of time that all `T`s were going to be a `Number`, you could restrict the generic parameter to any [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) (`<T extends Number>`) and use the `xxxValue()` methods to perform the calculations. Storing the result would probably require an abstract method `protected T getT(Number n)` or something similar.

Comment: That would work. But you'd have the overhead of boxing and unboxing for every operation. ==> If performance is not critical that's a good solution, but if performance matters I'd take another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Generics can't be used when creating an array because you don't know at runtime what type T is. This is called [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

The solution is simple: use `List<T> data`.

Comment: No I stated above I want arrays, list would be slower I think.

Comment: I can't see any reason in principle why type erasure should cause a problem for arrays. I think the reason they aren't allowed is mainly "because the language designers decided it". Now, type erasure *does* cause a problem for primitives. But an array of references should, in principle, be OK. I think.

Comment: @Nils, you're right. LinkedList would be slower. You should consider an ArrayList instead.

Comment: Well Aaron, that you don't see it doesn't mean it's not there ;-) Array know their component type at runtime, and must be told it upon creation. Generics don't know their type at runtime. So a generic type can not tell the array which type it should have, and that's why generic creation is impossible.

Comment: @meriton, I think you're missing the point a little. I did some research and made my own answer. Your observation on `T[]` applies just as well to `List<T>`. Arrays do *not* need to know their type, *as long as its a reference type*.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It is not true that this observation applies to `List<T>`. During runtime `List<T>` becomes `List`, so the class of `data` is clear. You can call the same methods on it, nothing is really changed. But what class should `T[]` become?

Comment: The array would be effectively `Object[]`, just as members a plain `List` are just Object. Plain old [`List` is quite similar to `List<Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Here's an example based on one from Effective Java. Say, T extends List<String>. `T[] stringLists = new T[1];` Let's suppose it's legal, though it's not. Now what if I do this: `List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(42); Object[] objects = stringLists; objects[0] = intList;` Now `stringLists` contains a reference to an object which is not of type T. T is now Object, so everything can be stored in this array, and you can't check it. Then we call `String str = stringLists[0].get(0)` and get a runtime error. So what would be the point of generics if they didn't guarantee type safety?

Comment: I agree, that is a problem. I described a similar example on another thread on this question. Even without generics, the ability to cast array types all over the place is a problem. So yeah, I'm going to heavily change my answer in order not to expose the `data` array publicly.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, if you control the access to the array and can guarantee the type checking, then it should work fine. I agree that such behavior of arrays can be considered deficient. So does Bloch, by the way, that's why he advises in Effective Java to prefer Lists over arrays when given a choice.

Comment: When I first answered this question, I didn't appreciate all that and I hadn't done my experiments thoroughly. So thanks for keeping me on my toes, @Malcolm!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you'll have to take another approach:

1. Type parameters must be reference types, they can't be primitive types.
2. Only reference types support polymorphism, and only for instance methods. Primitive types do not. float and double don't have a common supertype; you can not write an expression like a + b and choose at runtime whether to perform float addition or double addition. And since Java (unlike C++ or C#, which emit new code for each type parameter) uses the same bytecode for all instances of a generic type, you'd need polymorphism to use a different operator implementation.

If you really need this, I'd look into code generation, perhaps as part of an automated build. (A simple search & replace on the source ought to be able to turn a library operating on double into a library operating on float.)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, as long as you use `Float` and `Double` instead of `float` and `double`, as primitive types are not allowed in Java Generics. Of course, this will probably be quite slow. And, you won't be able to (safely) allow direct public access to the array. So this answer is not very useful, but it might be theoretically interesting. Anyway, how to construct the array ...

```
data = (T[]) new Object[arrayDim];
```

This will give you a warning, but it's not directly anything to worry about. It works in this particular form - it's inside a generic constructor and `data` is the only reference to this newly constructed object. [See this page about this.](http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node181.html)

You will not be able to access this array object publicly in the way you might like. You'll need to set up methods in `UniformGrid<T>` to get and set objects. This way, the compiler will ensure type-safety and the runtime won't give you any problems.

```
private T[] data;
public void set(int pos, T t) {
        data[pos] = t;
}
public T get(int pos) {
        return data[pos];
}
```

In this case, the interface to `set` will (at compile-time) enforce the correct type is passed. The underlying array is of type `Object[]` but that's OK as it can take any reference type - and all generic types are effectively `List<Object>` or something like that at runtime anyway.

The interesting bit is the getter. The compiler 'knows' that the type of `data` is `T[]` and hence the getter will compile cleanly and promises to return a `T`. So as long as you keep the `data` private and only access it through `get` and `set` then everything will be fine.

Some example code is on [ideone](http://ideone.com/BxEfz).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        UniformGrid<A> uf = new UniformGrid<A>(1);
        //uf.insert(0, new Object()); // compile error
        uf.insert(0, new A());
        uf.insert(0, new B());
        Object o1= uf.get(0);
        A      o2= uf.get(0);
        // B      o2= uf.get(0); // compiler error
        System.out.println(o1);
        System.out.println(o2);
        System.out.println("OK so far");
        // A via_array1 = uf.data[0]; // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LA;
}
```

As you would desire, there are compilation errors with `uf.insert(0, new Object())` and `B      o2= uf.get(0);`

But you shouldn't make the `data` member public. If you did, you could write and compile `A via_array1 = uf.data[0];`. That line looks like it should be OK, but you get a runtime exception: `Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LA;`.

In short, the `get` and `set` interface provide a safe interface. But if you go to this much trouble to use an array, you should just use an `ArrayList<T>` instead. Moral of the story: in any language (Java or C++), with generics or without generics, *just say no to arrays*. :-)

Comment: Thx for the answer, but.. will this be fast?

Comment: Generic array creation is impossible because arrays are reified, and generics are erased. That is, an array knows its element type, and checks that its elements are of that type. A generic type doesn't know the value of its type parameter at runtime. How then could a generic type create an array? The information about the component type is erased, but the array needs it to function as specified. Put differently, the bytecode instruction `anewarray` receives the desired element type as argument, but the instruction `new` that creates a new generic object doesn't.

Comment: (I've rethought my last tow comments and have deleted them. Noone else had replied at the moment of deletion.)

Comment: Consider a class `A` and a class that extends it called `B`. The following code *won't* compile: `List<B> lb = new ArrayList<B>();List<A> la = lb;` because the compiler won't let you treat a `List<B>` as if it was a `List<A>`. For example, it doesn't want to give you an easy way to try to insert an `A` into a list that should only contain `B`s. On the other hand, the compiler will let you write `B[] b = new B[8]; A[] a = b; a[1] = new A();` and you won't get any problem until runtime (*ArrayStoreException*). Essentially, I think this is a bad design for arrays in Java originally ...

Answer (score 0):

Item 25 in **Effective Java, 2nd Edition** talks about this problem:

> Arrays are covariant and reified; generics are invariant and erased.
>   As a consequence, arrays provide run-time type safety but not compile-time type safety and vice versa for generics. Generally speaking arrays and generics don't mix well.